# Why do we need the Hartman-Grobman theorem & the Stable Manifold Theorem to prove that any sink is asymptotically stable & source/saddle is unstable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading Perko's book on *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems (3e)* and I have the following question:

Why do we need the Hartman-Grobman theorem and the Stable Manifold Theorem to prove that any sink is asymptotically stable and source/saddle is unstable? Why is Hartman-Grobman not enough?

The passage in question is on p.130:

[image]

The following is said earlier, which I think makes implicitly use of Hartman-Grobman:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

**Attempt of an answer:**

**Sink:**
If we have a sink, then the eigenvalues of $Df(x_{0})$ are all less than zero. To show asymptotical stability I would apply the diffeomorphism from H-G-thm, i.e.

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}||\Phi_{t}(x)-x_{0}||=\lim_{t\to\infty}||H^{-1}\circ e^{At}H(x)-x_{0}||.$$

Then (hopefully) by continuity we have

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}||\Phi_{t}(x)-x_{0}||=\lim_{t\to\infty}||H^{-1}\circ e^{At}H(x)-x_{0}||=0,$$

since $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{At}H(x)=H(x_{0})$.

**Saddle/Source:** If we have a saddle then there are eigenvalues with positive and negative real part. Hence, $E^{s},E^{u}\neq\emptyset$. **By the Stable Manifold Theorem** it follows that $W^{s},W^{u}\neq\emptyset$, too, since they are of the same dimension as $E^{s},E^{u}$ respectively.  Hence, the stable manifold guarantees the existence of a trajectory that leaves any $B_{\epsilon}(x_{0})$. But then we can not have stability.

I hope it makes sense.

---

### **Theorems and Definitions:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *asymptotically*

Comment: It is probably worth explaining why you think there is a “need” for either of these things, and why you think “Hartman-Grobman” is sufficient. In detail.

Comment: I should have explained a little bit more, indeed. The book says that it follows from these two theorems. What I don’t understand is what we need the stable mfd. thm for. Can’t we conclude everting from Hartmann-Grobman, since we have a hyperbolic fixed point?

Comment: I don’t study the subject. If: “we have a hyperbolic fixed point”, then that is not apparent from the text in your post. Consider editing with further detail

Comment: I should say that I don’t study the subject. It seems to me that, if: “we have a hyperbolic fixed point”, that this is not apparent from the text in your post. That suggests to me that more is going on, that there is greater context. Consider editing to include more detail

Comment: It seems to be a simple separation of concerns, so that neither theorem is too claim-heavy. So the Hartman-Grobman theorem stops at the existence of the diffeomorphism to the linear model, while the stable-manifold theorem explores the geometric consequences of that diffeomorphism, without directly mentioning it in the claim. The (slightly) non-trivial part, apart from identifying the dimensions, is that these are indeed "differentiable manifolds". Mentioning both could be just simple emphasis that both theorems come in a closely connected union, as one "mega-theorem".

Comment: @LutzLehmann I humbly think that it is important that GH gives only a homeomorphism often.

Comment: @AlpUzman : Yes, that is indeed stated in the theorem. This makes the claim of a "differentiable manifold" even more non-trivial, as the homotopy now can not (always) serve as a differentiable map.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in fact the Stable Manifold Theorem is enough, instead of the other way around. In order to discuss if an equilibrium point is stable/asymptotically stable/unstable we would need unbounded times, but a priori the Hartman-Grobman Theorem gives a conjugacy local in time. On the other hand the Stable Manifold Theorem also gives information, albeit conditional, about the time intervals for which solutions are defined.

If $x_0$ is a sink, then by the Stable Manifold Theorem $x_0$ has an $n$-dimensional ball $B$ contained in the local stable manifold $\mathcal{S}_{x_0,\text{loc}}$ at $x_0$. By the forward invariance of stable manifolds $x_0$ is stable and by the limit property for any $y\in B$, $\lim_{t\to\infty} \phi_t(y)=x_0$.

If $x_0$ is a source or saddle, then again by the Stable Manifold Theorem the local unstable manifold $\mathcal{U}_{x_0,\text{loc}}$ at $x_0$ is not $0$-dimensional (i.e. the local unstable manifold contains points other than $x_0$). To show that $x_0$ is unstable we need to verify the following:

$$\exists \epsilon_0\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},\forall \delta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \exists y_\delta\in E,\exists t_\delta \in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}: d(y_\delta,x_0)<\delta, d(\phi_{t_\delta}(y_\delta),x_0)\geq\epsilon_0,$$

where $d$ is a distance on the open set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ (say the Euclidean distance).

Putting $z_\delta=\phi_{t_\delta}(y_\delta)$, we have $y_\delta=\phi_{-t_\delta}(z_\delta)$, this is equivalent to showing that

$$\exists \epsilon_0\in\mathbb{R}_{>0},\forall \delta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \exists z_\delta\in E,\exists t_\delta \in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}: d(\phi_{-t_\delta}(z_\delta),x_0)<\delta, d(z_\delta,x_0)\geq\epsilon_0.$$

Let $\epsilon_0$ be small enough so that there is a $z\in \mathcal{U}_{x_0,\text{loc}}$ such that $d(z,x_0)\geq\epsilon$. Then by the limiting property $\lim_{t\to\infty}d(\phi_{-t}(z),x_0)=0$. Then for any positive $\delta$, there is a time $t_\delta>0$ such that $d(\phi_{-t_\delta}(z),x_0)<\delta$. This shows that $x_0$ is unstable (the $z_\delta$ ends up not being dependent on $\delta$.)